# Appending tableview custom cells from two different nibs Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dictionary, uibutton

I have an `uitableview` with two custom-cell xib files (one has `uilabel`, second one `uibutton`).
What i do - 
 1. i append tableview with three cells (with `uilabel` - first xib)
 
 2. then i load the fourth cell with (with `uibutton` - second xib)

`uilabel` text is fetched from the array, `uibutton currentTitle` is also fetched, but from another array.

My goal is - upon the click of the `uibutton` it should append 1. next array of cells with `uilabel` and 2. 1 cell with `uibutton` from the corresponding array.

Here is my code for `tableview`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return linesmain["start"]!.count + 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {

    if(indexPath.row < someTagsArray.count){
        var cell:TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TblCell

        cell.lblCarName.text = linesmain["start"]![indexPath.row]

        return cell

    } else {
      var celle:vwAnswers = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2") as! vwAnswers
        celle.Answer1.setTitle(answersmain["start"]![0], forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        return celle
    }}
```

I know I should use something like `InsertRowsAtIndexPath`, but i have no idea how to implement it correctly in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
  tableView.beginUpdates()
     var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:row,inSection:0)
     var indexPath2 = NSIndexPath(forRow:row,inSection:0)
     self.tableView?.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath,indexPath2], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Reference Apple swift sample : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Listings/Swift_ListerToday_TodayViewController_swift.html

Comment: thank you! very good example. yet i'm wondering what if i need to insert multiple rows - what would the code for `NSIndexPath(forRow:row,inSection:0` be.

Comment: thank you, but what if i don't know the exact amount of rows - they are fetched dynamically from an array. there might be 2, might be three.

Comment: Just use for loop to create a array of indexPaths . Refer objective C code for logic https://xkong123.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/insertrowsatindexpaths-withrowanimation-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the change by using `[tableView beginEditing]`, modifying the table ui and the data as necessary, then `[tableView commitChanges]`

The quick way is to just update your data source and call `[tableView reloadData]`